# Which is the correct Syntax for passing data from datagrid to access database in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, syntax, oledb

I want to fill a local access database with data from datagridview. I've added the database to the  project, its use is only local. I've copied the connectionstring and build up the query for passing the data into the access table. I'm entering the data from another ViewForm1, so I do not access the database at the time im adding data into it.

I build the project, navigate to the form, write data to the tables and press add. The result is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Syntaxfehler in der INSERT INTO-Anweisung."
>   Diese Ausnahme wurde ursprünglich bei dieser Aufrufliste ausgelöst:
>       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbHResult)
>       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(System.Data.OleDb.tagDBPARAMS, out object)
>       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(out object)
>       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(System.Data.CommandBehavior, out object)
>       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(System.Data.CommandBehavior, string)
>       System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>       vdefinder.databasecontrol.addToTableBtn_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in databasecontrol.cs
>       System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>       System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>       System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
>       ...
>       [Aufrufliste abgeschnitten]

If I do not enter anything to the datagridviewcells - no error appears as I press the Addbutton.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace vdefinder
{
    public partial class databasecontrol : Form
    {
        public databasecontrol()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void backToLoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            login li = new login();
            li.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void addToTableBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\_VS_Projekte\vdefinder\vdefinder\vdefinder.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO vdefinder (Index, Kategorie, Inhalt) VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value+"')", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Data saved to table.");
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the vivencio2's solution. By the way, I suggest that you don't set the database name as the table name. Sometimes it may result in confict.

Answer (score 1):

The error has something to do with the insert statement syntax. You might want to check the passed parameter of the line below:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO vdefinder (Index, Kategorie, Inhalt) VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value+"')", con);
```

I believe you only have 2 values while you actually need 3 for Index, Kategorie and Inhalt.